# Check / uncheck the array of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

Here is what I have (twitter bootstrap is used here)

```
#html
 <ul id="my-categories">
    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input checked="checked" name="supername[]" type="checkbox" value="43243">fdsfdsfds
      </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input checked="checked" name="supername[]" type="checkbox" value="21343">sadsadsadsadsd
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="fdsfds"></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="my-categories-btn">Check/Uncheck all</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

 # js file
 $("#my-categories-btn").click(function(){
    $("my-categories input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        isChecked = $(this).attr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', !isChecked);
    });
  })
```

it just doesn't work for some reason.

How do I fix it?

Comment: fyi, use `.prop()` and not `.attr()` for things like checked, readonly and disabled. you are also leaking a global variable since you forgot the `var` in front of `isChecked`

Comment: thanks. but why should I use prop()?

Comment: Because it returns a boolean rather than the string value. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Also, do you want to toggle the current selections or actually check or uncheck all checkboxes?

Comment: @Stefan, you are totally right. I want to check/uncheck all. I just paid attention to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use a checkbox instead of the link you are using for checking/unchecking all checkboxes.

This way it´s possible to determine wether or not to check or uncheck all the checkboxes rather than just toggling their current state.

```
$('#my-categories-btn').change(function() {
    $('#my-categories input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});​
```

See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fgBMx/)** using an extra checkbox.

Comment: That's a very interesting approach.

Comment: Great! You can even hide the extra checkbox if you don´t want it to look like one of the options as it´s just there to hold the selection. `#my-categories-btn { display: none; }`

Answer (score 4):

You missed the `#` with my-categories also need to change `this` to `$(this)` to call `attr()` jQuery function because `this` give you **DOM** object and `$(this)` gives **jQuery** object and attribute could be called with jQuery object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XRWG4/1/)**

```
$("#my-categories-btn").click(function(){
    $("#my-categories input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
})
```

You **do not need each** here you can directly assign value to checked property

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XRWG4/2/)**

```
$("#my-categories-btn").click(function() {
    $("#my-categories input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', false);
});​
```

For both **checking and unchecking** you can use the checked status of your checkbox collection.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XRWG4/4/)**

```
$("#my-categories-btn").click(function() {
    lst = $("#my-categories input[type=checkbox]");
    $(lst).attr('checked', !lst[0].checked);
});​
```

Comment: what about checked = true?

Comment: Updated my answer @AlanDert for both check and uncheck using anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `my-categories` as an id selector by prefixing with a `#`

```
 $("#my-categories-btn").click(function(){
    $("#my-categories input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        isChecked = $(this).attr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', !isChecked);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your script-code accordingly.

```
$("#my-categories-btn").click(function(){
    $("#my-categories input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        isChecked = $(this).attr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', !isChecked);
    });
  })
```